# MySQL caching with GO

Tags: mysql, go

I have a Go app which runs queries with lots of joins (using a legacy DB).

Its  killing the speed of my app. Is there any caching libraries out there that might help speed up the response times?

I've done a bit of searching but can't seem to find anything that fits.

Comment: https://github.com/mgutz/dat can use Redis as a query cache, but I would strongly dig into whether you can optimize those queries. You may have tried some of this already (?) but denormalising tables, better indexes, etc are going to be better long-term. Using Redis may not be a silver bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently exists this well done caching library developed directly by the golang team: [groupcache](https://github.com/golang/groupcache)

Comment: Beware of it for MySQL caching, as it has no built in invalidation mechanism. Things are just cached forever, it's just a distributed LRU. It doesn't even have expiration. You can achieve it by key manipulation, but it's not trivial.